# Way to disable Rails SQL logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to disable SQL logs in Rails, other than changing the log level? I've got some logger.debug statements that I'd like to print out in my ActiveRecord models, but I want to hide the SQL statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can moneky-patch it, put this in a file such as `config/initializers/disable_ar_logging.rb`:

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter
  def log_info(*args); end
end
```

Comment: This answer looks out of date, It doesn't work for my using active_record 4.2.8

Answer (score 1):

Dan,

Is this in production or development mode? If it's development mode this is usually what I do:

```
logger.info("DEBUG my message here")
logger.info("DEBUG #{my_object.inspect}")

tail -f log/development | grep DEBUG
```

Comment: This isn't helpful, it does not at all disable logging.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me in Rails 3.0.5:

```
  class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter
    def log(sql, name)
      name ||= "SQL"
      yield
    rescue Exception => e
      message = "#{e.class.name}: #{e.message}: #{sql}"
      @logger.debug message if @logger
      raise translate_exception(e, message)
    end
  end
```

It's [this method](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.5/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractAdapter/log) with the line that writes to the log removed. SQL cache hits are still displayed in the log and I haven't figured out how to disable those.