# Disable SQL logging in terminal during testing with Rails 3.1? (RSPEC/Cucumber)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I just upgraded my app to rails 3.1 and now whenever I run tests I get a ton of SQL output in my terminal.

For example:

```
   (1.0ms)  TRUNCATE TABLE `users`;
   (0.1ms)  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1
.  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` LIMIT 1
  Sector Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `sectors`.* FROM `sectors` WHERE `sectors`.`name` = 'General' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `sectors` WHERE `sectors`.`name` = BINARY 'General 63' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `sectors` (`created_at`, `name`, `price_in_cents`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2011-09-13 20:46:48', 'General 63', 0, '2011-09-13 20:46:48')
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
```

Is there any way to disable this?

I'm using rspec instafail and I can't seem them anymore because its flooded with SQL output.

I tried adding what was in this article but it didnt help: http://tesoriere.com/2011/05/28/rails-3.1---sql-logging-to-stdout-during-testing--with-rspec--test-unit--or-cucumber-/

Comment: You could try the suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635112/way-to-disable-rails-sql-logs

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried setting the `config.log_level` in your environments/test.rb?

```
config.log_level = :error
```

That would be the easiest solution, unless there's a reason it's not working.