# When I run rspec, I see some database output, that overflows console and I can't see really important test info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

It seems, that rspec use ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration in each test case
[it's part of my console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmzcq.png). What to do to prevent wasteful database usage and how to fix my console output?

Comment: Did you consider not adding the `d` command line option? for example, run the command `rspec -f`

Comment: Thanks for the help,  Tamer! 
I just find the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408270/disable-sql-logging-in-terminal-during-testing-with-rails-3-1-rspec-cucumber